# ¿Como realizo un insert en dos tablas diferentes en el método store de laravel 8?

Tags: php7, laravel-8

Quiero hacer un insert en 2 tablas distintas de la base de datos. tengo la tabla permisos y la tabla permisos contestados, en la cual la primera tabla guarda los permisos y la segunda los permisos contestados, en el momento tengo lo siguiente:

**Modelos**:

```
    `<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class permiso extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}`





`<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PermisoContestado extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}`
```

**Controlador:** Donde guardo en tabla permisos los datos del permiso eso me funciono pero cuando intento guardar en Permisos Contestados no me funciona, apenas estoy empezando a trabajar con laravel y no se como hacerlo

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Models\permiso;
    use App\Models\PermisoContestado;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use PDF;
    use GuzzleHttp;

 
    class PermisoController extends Controller{

    public function store(Request $request)
        {
            //insertando en la tabla de permisos
            $datospermiso = request()->except('_token');
            if($request->hasFile('Documentos', )){
                $datospermiso['Documentos']=$request->file('Documentos')->store('uploads','public');
            }
            permiso::insert($datospermiso);
            return response()->json($datospermiso);
    
            //insertando en la tabla de permisoscontestados
            $pcontestado = request()->except('_token');
            PermisoContestado::insert($pcontestado);
            return response()->json($pcontestado);
            
        }
 }
```

**Vista:** En la vista estoy recogiendo los datos de la tabla permiso y para guardarlos en la tabla permisos contestados la vista la tengo nombrada como; permisoctado.blade.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<body>
        <div class="container" >
            <form action="{{ url('/Permiso') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf 
            @foreach($permisos as $permiso)
            <div class="row justify-content-center" >
            <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-header" style=" border: 2px solid #3AA5FF;border-radius: 20px;"> 
            <div class="py-5 text-left" >  
                <div class="col-12">
                  <h1 align="center"> Formulario de Notificación de Permisos</h1>
                </div> 
                <br> 
                 <div class="col-12">
                  <label for="inputAddress" class="form-label">En la Fecha</label>
                  <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-calendar2-week-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M3.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1h8V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V1h1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm9.954 3H2.545c-.3 0-.545.224-.545.5v1c0 .276.244.5.545.5h10.91c.3 0 .545-.224.545-.5v-1c0-.276-.244-.5-.546-.5zM8.5 7a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1zm3 0a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1zM3 10.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5zm3.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1z"/>
                      </svg>
                    </span>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control form-control" name ="Fechah" id="Fechah" placeholder="" value="{{ $permiso->Fechar}}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="col-12"> 
                  <label  class="form-label" for="Nombre">Se Comunica a </label>   
                  <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M3 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4-1 1-1 1H3zm5-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z"/>
                      </svg>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text"  name="Nombre" id="Nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Nombre Completo" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping" value="{{$permiso->Nombre}}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br> 
                <div class="col-12">
                  <label for="inputAddress" class="form-label">Que el Permiso para el Día</label>
                  <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-calendar2-week-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M3.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1h8V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V1h1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm9.954 3H2.545c-.3 0-.545.224-.545.5v1c0 .276.244.5.545.5h10.91c.3 0 .545-.224.545-.5v-1c0-.276-.244-.5-.546-.5zM8.5 7a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1zm3 0a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1zM3 10.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5zm3.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1z"/>
                      </svg>
                    </span>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control form-control" name ="Fechad" id="Fechad" placeholder="Ej:Instituto Técnico Agropecuario Naranjal" value="{{$permiso->Fechap}}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="col-12">
                  <label for="ciudad_idciudad" class="form-label">Fue</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="Respuesta" name="Respuesta">
                    <option value="Aprobado">Aprobado</option>
                    <option value="Desaprobado">Desaprobado</option>
                  </select>
                    </div>
                <br>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Motivo</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name ="Motivo" id="Motivo" rows="3" value=""><?php echo $permiso["Motivo"]?></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <label for="inputAddress" class="form-label">Teléfono Celular</label>
                    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                      <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-phone" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                          <path d="M11 1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h6zM5 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h6a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H5z"/>
                          <path d="M8 14a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2z"/>
                        </svg>
                       </span>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Telefonoc" id="Telefonoc" placeholder="" value="{{$permiso->Telefonoc}}">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Enviar Datos">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
            </form>
        </div>    
    </body>
```

**Ruta:** en la ruta definí las siguientes direcciones en web

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('Permiso', PermisoController::class);

Route::get('/PDF/permiso' , 'App\Http\Controllers\PermisoController@generarPdf')->name('PDF.permiso');

Route::get('/PDF/whatsapp' , 'App\Http\Controllers\PermisoController@notificarPermiso');

Route::get('/PDF/gestion', 'App\Http\Controllers\PermisoController@gestionarPermiso')->name('PDF.gestion');

Route::get('/PDF/permisoctado' , 'App\Http\Controllers\permisoController@contestarPermiso')->name('PDF.permisoctado');
```

El error que me aparece es el siguiente

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Fechah' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `permisos` (`Fechah`, `Nombre`, `Fechad`, `Respuesta`, `Motivo`, `Telefonoc`) values (2021-04-05, Alexis Pescador, 2021-04-17, Aprobado, Por motivos del proyecto de grado, 3234690120))
```

Comment: Lo que esta después del primer return no se ejecutará

Answer (score 0):

lo primero que debes saber es que no debes tener dos `return` dentro de una función, debido a que el `return` termina la ejecucion de la funcion. por lo tanto todo lo que tengas por debajo del `return` no se va a ejecutar.

Te comento el error que te muestra el sistema:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Fechah' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `permisos` (`Fechah`, `Nombre`, `Fechad`, `Respuesta`, `Motivo`, `Telefonoc`) values (2021-04-05, Alexis Pescador, 2021-04-17, Aprobado, Por motivos del proyecto de grado, 3234690120))
```

Te esta indicando que en la Tabla `permisos` no existe la columna `Fechah`, te recomiendo revises las migraciones de base de datos de tu proyecto y verifiques la existencia de esa columna dentro de dicha tabla.

Ahora para registrar varios puedes intentar esto

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //insertando en la tabla de permisos

    //indicando dentro de ONLY las variables que se van a registrar
    $datospermiso = $request->only(["Nombre", "Motivo", "Telefonoc"]);
    if ($request->hasFile('Documentos', )) {
        $datospermiso['Documentos'] = $request->file('Documentos')->store('uploads', 'public');
    }
    permiso::create($datospermiso);

    //insertando en la tabla de permisoscontestados
    $pcontestado = $request->only(["Nombre", "Motivo", "Telefonoc"]);
    PermisoContestado::create($pcontestado);
    return response()->json($pcontestado);

}
```

Aplicando el Only a la variable `$request` puedes obtener las variables que solamente necesitas para cada tabla.